# converting mashape api response to php string

Tags: php, mashape

Below is my code, I am trying to get particular mashape api response (operator) in php string.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$response = Unirest\Request::get("https://sphirelabs-mobile-number-portability-india-operator-v1.p.mashape.com/index.php?number=8055144322",
array(
"X-Mashape-Key" => "XXXXXXXXX",
"Accept" => "application/json"
)
);
json_decode($response, true);
echo $response['operator'];
```

Response:

```
Unirest\Response Object ( 
  [code] => 200 
  [raw_body] => {"Telecom circle":"Maharashtra","Operator":"Reliance GSM","Is MNP":"False"} 
  [body] => stdClass Object ( 
       [Telecom circle] => Maharashtra 
       [Operator] => Reliance GSM 
       [Is MNP] => False 
   ) 
   [headers] => Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Accept-Ranges] => none [Content-Encoding] => gzip [Content-Type] => application/json [Date] => Thu, 19 Feb 2015 14:04:39 GMT [Server] => Mashape/5.0.6 [Vary] => Accept-Encoding [Content-Length] => 91 [Connection] => keep-alive ) )
```

Comment: Sounds like the result you're getting isn't json. Post the results of `print_r($response)` so we can see what you're dealing with.

Comment: I already try print_r($response) and  i am getting all api response in json correctly but i want  particular response (operator) from api.

Comment: The error in your question tells me `$response` isn't json.

Comment: I edited my code. Now, Please resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `json_decode` this. It's already a php Object.

`$response->body->Operator` should give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: Getting error "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Unirest\Response as array".